# How to prevent syslogging "Error inserting nvidia" on cudaGetDeviceCount()?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, syslog

I have a tool that can be run on both, GPU and CPU. In some init-step I check `cudaGetDeviceCount()` for the available GPUs. If the tool is being executed on a node without video cards, this results in the following syslog message:

```
Sep 13 00:21:10 [...] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
```

How can I prevent the nvidia driver from flooding my syslog server with this message? It's OK if the node doesn't have a video card, it's not that critical, so I just want to get rid of the message.

Comment: May be check for alternative options by using a system command. You can check to see if there are any `/dev/nvidia*` nodes

Comment: why not just configure the local syslog daemon to surpass that class of message?

Comment: Sure I can do that, I just hoped for some nicer solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That message gets inserted into the syslog by the NVIDIA driver.  So the most direct solution would be to not install the NVIDIA driver on a node that does not have a GPU.

If you need some NVIDIA driver components on that node, for example to build CUDA driver API codes on a GPU-less login node, then you will need to use some special switches during driver installation.

You can find out more about driver install switches by using the --help switch on the driver installer package.

A sequence of switches like this may do the trick:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run --no-nvidia-modprobe --no-kernel-module --no-kernel-module-source -z
```